# Error report - ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS' for newly installed sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, privileges

I am connecting the Pre Built HR Schema to the Oracle 21C using SQL Developer. I created a new tablespace **USERS** and User **HR**.

```
    CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED hr;
    GRANT CONNECT TO hr;
    GRANT CREATE SESSION, GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE TO hr;    
    GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO hr;
    GRANT CREATE TABLE TO hr;
```

The **HR** User is connected Successfully however, The data in the tables of HR Schema isn't [showing][https://i.stack.imgur.com/74mj5.png] and I cannot INSERT, UPDATE AND ALTER. Only [SELECT][https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZnWj.png] AND CREATE TABLE are Working.

I tried these as a SYS User:

```
    ALTER USER quota unlimited on hr;
    ALTER USER hr quota 100M on users;
    ALTER USER hr QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
    grant resource to hr ;
    grant unlimited tablespace to hr ;
    grant all privileges to hr ;
    grant dba to hr ;
    grant create session to hr;
    grant create table to hr;
    grant create procedure to hr;
    grant create sequence to hr;
    grant create view to hr;
    grant create trigger to hr;
    select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;
```

Tablespace names[https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQpho.png]

Still, I am getting error's as:

```
Error report -
    ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

[no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'][https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVTzE.png]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error says that you don't have privilege on tablespace `USERS`. Did you create `HR` user yourself, or are you using pre-built schema (you already got when you installed Oracle database)?

Here's a script which shows *how* to do that so that most basic things work.

Connected as e.g. `SYS` (if you don't have any other user with DBA privileges), check list of tablespaces. Let's presume that `users` and `temp` are among them (as they will be used in `create user`):

```
select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;
```

Create user:

```
create user hr identified by hr
  default tablespace users
  temporary tablespace temp
  profile default
  quota  unlimited on users;
```

Grant some privileges:

```
grant create session       to hr;
grant create table         to hr;
grant create procedure     to hr;
grant create sequence      to hr;
grant create view          to hr;
grant create trigger       to hr;
```

---

**[EDIT]** After you edited question and posted commands you ran, I didn't just *look* at it, but also executed everything you did.

I'm connected as `sys`:

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
```

Outcome is rather poor because the very **first** command you posted is invalid:

```
SQL> CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED hr;
CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED hr
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00924: missing BY keyword
```

I fixed it; here's how it goes (still connected as `sys`):

```
SQL>     CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED by hr;

User created.

SQL>     GRANT CONNECT TO hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     GRANT CREATE SESSION, GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE TO hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     GRANT CREATE TABLE TO hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     ALTER USER quota unlimited on hr;
    ALTER USER quota unlimited on hr
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


SQL>     ALTER USER hr quota 100M on users;

User altered.

SQL>     ALTER USER hr QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;

User altered.

SQL>     grant resource to hr ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant unlimited tablespace to hr ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant all privileges to hr ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant dba to hr ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant create session to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant create table to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant create procedure to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant create sequence to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant create view to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>     grant create trigger to hr;

Grant succeeded.
```

*Almost everything* went well; the one that also failed doesn't matter much.

I'll connect as newly created `hr` user and do some operations:

```
SQL> connect hr/hr@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

As you can see, no problem.

---

I can't be sure what you really did and how Oracle responded because - as I already said - `create user` is invalid so everything else you posted can't possibly work because user doesn't exist. Did you *fake* some other things as well, I can't tell.

By the way, you're about to grant way **too many privileges** to `hr` user. Why do you think that it should be granted `dba`? Is it safe?

Why didn't you use code I posted? That's kind of *enough* to let any "ordinary" user work:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> drop user hr cascade;

User dropped.

SQL> create user hr identified by hr
  2    default tablespace users
  3    temporary tablespace temp
  4    profile default
  5    quota  unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session       to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table         to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create procedure     to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create sequence      to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create view          to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create trigger       to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect hr/hr@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank You sir, it does granted some privileges. But it didn't solved my issue, I am still facing same issue.

Comment: Could you post (copy/paste) all steps you did? Not in a comment, of course - that would be difficult to read. Edit the original question and post as many data as possible.

Comment: I have Edited my Question, Can you Help me Sort it out.

Comment: I edited answer, based on what you posted. Have a look, please.